# Deny public access to directory, but allow iframe to access

Tags: .htaccess, directory

I have a certain directory, `/home/secret`, to only be accessible by iframes from my website. How can I do this without allowing normal browsers and such access to it? I have tried setting permission to 750, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: iframe access is also public access

Comment: Is there any way to do it, then?

Comment: Thing is, users can create their own folders inside there, and I don't want other people to be access their folder from a URL except themselves via iframe.

Comment: So the users can change the content of their directory, so I can't add any of my own script.

Comment: My answer offers 3 ways you can go about doing this.

Comment: I can't have anything in that directory, because the user can change all of the content in it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest maybe adding a **GET variable** to the end of the url and only allowing it that way, or checking the **REFERRER** and if that doesn't exist, simply killing the script.

If you would like to limit it to a user, I'd simply suggest making a login system and then passing the **cookie** to the file and having the file verify that the cookie is that user, THEN allowing access to the file.

The only problem with try to do this is that all of these settings can be spoofed with a **cURL or some other form of a browser-mimic software**.

Hope this helped!